# How to find php error log files or to see execution errors with netbeans PHP built-in web server?

Tags: php, netbeans, runtime-error, logfile

I am using the netbeans 8.0.2 PHP built-in web server to develop a an application in PHP using Ubuntu 14.04. Although I have set

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
display_errors = on
```

I am not able to see the execution errors or even to find log files with these execution errors. The error.log file is /var/log/apache2/ but it does not seem to report the errors that I have been facing.

Where should I look for these errors?
I there a way to see in the html page the execution errors?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like [netbeans use default php built-in server](https://blogs.oracle.com/netbeansphp/entry/php_5_4_support_built). So you should try to configure loging in your php.ini. Or use custom error handler.

Comment: Yes, this is the basic window. The configuration is working well. The point is that where the log files are saved... Or how to save them somewhere? I am not able to see this option at this configuration window.

Comment: @DanielTheRocketMan, custom error handler its not feature of IDE, its ability in PHP to use custom exception-handling mechanism. You may look [this page](http://php.net/manual/book.errorfunc.php). For example you could logging exceptions in custom format, or email it. As for server, try to launch [php server](http://php.net/manual/features.commandline.webserver.php) directly. You'll see all messages(errors too) in your terminal (`php -S localhost:8888`).